# Executing Octave Program within C

Tags: c, octave

I've created an image analysis program in Octave that I would like to call from within a C executable program. I have no idea how to call the octave interpreter from within a C code (NOT C++). I'm quite the programming novice, so any help or advice would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: `system(what_you_want_to_execute_in_shell);`

Answer (score 0):

You can use `execv(octave_executable,other arguments)` , `execvp(....)` or any other system call from this family.